# Memory never goes down when I use the UIImageJPEGRepresentation in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, base64, uiimagejpegrepresentation

Im building an framework that returning a string image in B64

this is my line code

I'm using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to reduce the image and then make it B64

```
imageb64Min = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

but every I use this line in my application flow, the memory never goes down
reaches the limit memory of the application and break the app

[image: Memory Report]

any idea why does this?

**EDIT:** this is my code flow

```
    func arregloImagenesConDNI(arrImagenes: NSArray, tipoDocumento: TipoDocumento, codigoDNI: BAZQRScan.eCodigo, dni: String)
    {
        NSLog("Arreglo de Imagenes: %@", arrImagenes.description)
//        let ecodigo = codigoDNI as! Int
        var fileNames: Array = Array <String>();
        var imagesMin: Array = Array <String>();
        //for var index = 0; index < arrImagenes.count; index += 1
        var imageb64:String?
        var imageb64Min:String?
        for index in 0 ..< arrImagenes.count {

            let image:UIImage? = (arrImagenes[index] as? UIImage)

            imageb64 = ABANKUtil.encodeToBase64String(image)
//            [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
//            let imageb64:String = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            let identifier:String = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString

            let keys: Array = Array(arrayLiteral: "name", "resource")

            let dataToSave:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objects: [identifier, imageb64!], forKeys: keys);

            //            [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

            imageb64Min = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

            // Not really temp files
            let sessionPath:String = String(format: "%@%@", ABANKUtil.getDocsPath(), identifier)

            NSLog("Create file at path: %@", sessionPath);

            dataToSave.writeToFile(sessionPath, atomically: true)

            fileNames.append(identifier)
            imagesMin.append(imageb64Min!)
        }

        let jsonNames:NSMutableString = "["


        let jsonImages:NSMutableString = "[";
        // for var index = 0; index < arrImagenes.count; index += 1
        for index in 0 ..< arrImagenes.count {

            if index == 0{
                jsonNames.appendFormat("\"%@\"", fileNames[index])
                jsonImages.appendFormat("\"%@\"", imagesMin[index])
            }
            else {
                jsonNames.appendFormat(",\"%@\"", fileNames[index])
                jsonImages.appendFormat(",\"%@\"", imagesMin[index])
            }
        }

        jsonNames.appendString("]")  
        jsonImages.appendString("]")

        print("JsonImages: \(jsonImages)")

        print("JsonNames: \(jsonNames)")

        let respuesta : String = "{\"codigo\": 0, \"mensaje\": \"Se capturaron las fotos\",\"arrArchBase64\": \(jsonImages) ,\"arrNomArchBase64\": \(jsonNames) ,\"DNI\": \"\(dni)\" ,\"codigoDNI\": \"\(codigoDNI)\"}"
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            print("Send response  digi")
            self.webview?.send(respuesta, callback: self.callback!, scope: self.module!)
        }
        imageb64 = nil
        imageb64Min = nil
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: If you look at the `length` of the data object returned by  `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0)`, I suspect it won't be that large. Is the original `image` reference getting released (because that's going to take a lot more memory than the data)? If you look in allocations, what objects are not getting released here?

Comment: @diego Show the code flow, I suspect you just keep the reference to your B64 images and never release them.

Comment: Profile for memory leak!

Comment: Hello @Lawicko , this is my code Flow, add to original post

Comment: @DiegoPalomares for each image you do `imagesMin.append(imageb64Min!)` so this is why it keeps all the images until the end of this method. If your problem is that the images persist outside of the `arregloImagenesConDNI` method then you need to show the entire context.

Comment: @lawicko , arregloImagenesConDNI method is a delegate from another framework, I receive the response with the  images array , my work is to reduce images  and convert them to B64 and return to the front. but each time I reduce and convert one  the memory is never down. 
when I monitoring with Breakpoints  and reaches that line of code 

imageb64Min = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

 the memory goes up. my execution ends and the  memory never goes down during the life of the application

Comment: @Diego ok, I see, I'd suggest commenting out your code one by one and checking when the memory starts behaving as expected. There are many things that can go wrong here, for example the `self.webview?.send` may as well retain the `respuesta` object and this is why it's not released. This is just a guess, but the code is pretty simple and short, so just comment it out line by line and you will find it.